# How to fix "Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: bigip" errors, works in Ansible, NOT Tower

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am running Ansible Tower v3.4.1 with Ansible v2.7.6 on an ubuntu 16.04 VM running on VirtualBox. I run a playbook that works when I run it from the command line using "ansible-playbook" but fails when I try to run it from Ansible Tower. I know I must have something misconfigured in ansible tower but I can't find it.

I get this warning no matter what changes I make to the inventory (hosts) file.

```
$ ansible-playbook 2.7.6

config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg    
configured module search path = [u'/var/lib/awx/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']

ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible    

executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:36:49) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

SSH password:     
**/tmp/awx_74_z6yJB4/tmpVlXGCX did not meet host_list requirements**, check plugin documentation if this is unexpected

Parsed /tmp/awx_74_z6yJB4/tmpVlXGCX inventory source with script plugin

PLAYBOOK: addpool.yaml *********************************************************

1 plays in addpool.yaml

 [WARNING]: **Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: bigip**

PLAY [Sample pool playbook] ****************************************************
17:05:43

skipping: no hosts matched
```

I have enabled inventory plugins for YAML, and made my hosts file into a `hosts.yml` file.

Here's my hosts file:

```
 192.168.68.253
 192.168.68.254
 192.168.1.165

[centos]
dad2 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.165

[bigip]
bigip1 ansible_host=192.168.68.254
bigip2 ansible_host=192.168.68.253
```

Here's my playbook:

```
---

- name: Sample pool playbook
  hosts: bigip 
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: create web servers pool
      bigip_pool:
        name: web-servers2
        lb_method: ratio-member
        password: admin
        user: admin
        server: '{{inventory_hostname}}'
        validate_certs: no
```

Answer (score 5):

I replaced `hosts: bigip` with `hosts: all` and specified the inventory in Tower as `bigip` which contains only the two hosts I want to change. This seems to provide the output I am looking for.

For the `ansible-playbook` command line, I added `--limit bigip` and this seems to provide the output I am looking for.

So things appear to be working, I just don't know whether this is *best practice* use.

Comment: did you figure out a best practice since ? I'm facing the same issue and except configure hosts: all, there's nothing that seems to work..

Answer (score 1):

If you get the error below while running a playbook with the command

```yaml
ansible-playbook -i test-project/inventory.txt playbook.yml
```

> {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 172.31.24.10 port 22: Connection timed out", "unreachable": true}

The solution is to add, in the file *ansible.cfg*:

```ini
[defaults]

inventory=/etc/ansible/hosts
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the `connection: local`.

You have specified in `hosts: bigip` that you want these tasks to only run on hosts in the `bigip` group. You then specify `connection: local` which causes the task to run on the controller node (i.e. localhost), rather than the nodes in the `bigip` group. Localhost is not a member of the `bigip` group, and so none of the tasks in the play will trigger.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but that's a little confusing, because that playbook runs properly from the command line using "ansible-playbook". It only fails running from Tower. What would you use for "connection" in Tower?

Comment: By the way, I get the same error result when I remove "connection: local"

Answer (score 0):

Check for special characters in absolute path of hosts file or playbook. Incase if you directly copied the path from putty, try copy and paste it from notepad or any editor

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the format of the `/etc/ansible/hosts` file. You should use the `:children` suffix in order to use groups of groups like this:

```
[dev1]
dev_1 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.55 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user={{username}} ansible_ssh_pass={{password}} 

[dev2]
dev_2 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.1.68 ansible_connection=ssh ansible_ssh_user={{username}} ansible_ssh_pass={{password}}

[devs:children]
dev1
dev2
```

Reference: [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)